# K8S, nodeType port could not map POD port. nodeType port mapped as tcp6 protocol, not tcp

Tags: kubernetes

I have a win10 machine, where I created a CentOS 7.5 virtual machine. I have one simple pod and svc, I make NodeType type of svc, but I failed to map local port 30003 to pod port 8080.

shinyinfo-jenkins-pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: shinyinfo-jenkins
 labels:
   app: shinyinfo-jenkins
spec:
 containers:
   - name: shinyinfo-jenkins
     image: shinyinfo_jenkins
     imagePullPolicy: Never
     ports:
       - containerPort: 8080
         containerPort: 50000
```

shinyinfo-jenkins-svc.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: shinyinfo-jenkins-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    port: 8080
    nodePort: 30003
  selector:
    app: shinyinfo-jenkins
```

with two yaml files, I do:

```
sudo kubectl apply -f shinyinfo-jenkins-pod.yaml
sudo kubectl apply -f shinyinfo-jenkins-svc.yaml
```

I login into pod: I could do `curl localhost:8080`, I see it is accessible.

```
jenkins@shinyinfo-jenkins:/$ curl localhost:8080
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/> 
     <script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');
     </script>
  </head>
  <body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>

Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

  </body>
</html>
```

It tries to redirect to login page.

Then in virtual machine, I opened firefox, I type `localhost:30003` in firefox address bar, it continuously try to connect the server, but it hangs there.

The log show nothing wrong:

```
[master@master1 config]$ sudo kubectl logs shinyinfo-jenkins
[sudo] password for master:
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Nov 01, 2018 7:45:05 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @2136ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
...
Nov 01, 2018 7:45:16 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
...

Nov 01, 2018 7:45:32 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

The port seems run as tcp6 protocol, not tcp.

```
[master@master1 config]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 30003
[sudo] password for master:
tcp6       2      0 :::30003                :::*                    LISTEN      5208/kube-proxy
tcp6     316      0 ::1:30003               ::1:48096               CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp6      80      0 ::1:30003               ::1:53132               CLOSE_WAIT  -
```

Can some expert here gives me some hints?

===================================================

## Edition 2

I am using kubernetes cluster configuration, not minikube. I tried to connect pod port and vm port, pod port(`8080`) connection works, but not vm port(`30003`). And initially port `30003` is not binded to any process. When in vm, I tried `curl localhost:30003`, it creates `CLOSE_WAIT` record in command `sudo netstats -anp | grep 30003`. I just could not figure out why `30003` could not map to pod port `8080`. How to check service port?

```
[master@master1 config]$ sudo kubectl get po
NAME                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysql               1/1       Running   0          36s
redis               1/1       Running   0          1m
shinyinfo-jenkins   1/1       Running   0          8s

[master@master1 config]$ sudo kubectl apply -f shinyinfo-jenkins-svc.yaml
service/shinyinfo-jenkins-svc created

[master@master1 config]$ curl localhost:30003
^C

[master@master1 config]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 30003
tcp6       1      0 :::30003                :::*                    LISTEN      5235/kube-proxy
tcp6      80      0 ::1:30003               ::1:53126               CLOSE_WAIT  -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53126               ::1:30003               FIN_WAIT2   -

[master@master1 config]$ sudo kubectl exec -it shinyinfo-jenkins -- /bin/bash

jenkins@shinyinfo-jenkins:/$ curl localhost:8080
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            jenkins@shinyinfo-jenkins:/$

jenkins@shinyinfo-jenkins:/$ exit
exit

[master@master1 config]$
```

=============================================================

## Third edition

When config vm network, I create host only adapter, which has address `192.168.56.103 (enp0s8)`, and NAT for vm connect to internet which has ipv4 address
`10.0.2.9 (enp0s3)`, both work when I do `curl 192.168.56.103:30003` and `curl 10.0.2.9:30003`.
Both work. Why curl `localhost:30003` does not work？ Something related to my `/etc/hosts`? I put my `/ect/hosts` at bottom of this edition.

```
[master@master1 ~]$ sudo kubectl get svc
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes              ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          1h
shinyinfo-jenkins-svc   NodePort    10.101.23.232   <none>        8080:30003/TCP   1h

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[master@master1 ~]$ curl 10.101.23.232:8080
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            [master@master1 ~]$

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    
[master@master1 ~]$ curl 10.0.2.9:30003
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
[master@master1 ~]$ curl 192.168.56.103:30003
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html> 

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[master@master1 ~]$ ifconfig
cali06603f21a57: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1440
        inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
 '''

calie7aebb24de0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1440
        inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:8c:b5:7b:d9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        ...
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.9  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::df00:5aa6:15fa:1bea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ...
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::92c6:2f30:8517:e40b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ...
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        ...
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tunl0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1440
        inet 100.97.40.64  netmask 255.255.255.255
        tunnel   txqueuelen 1000  (IPIP Tunnel)
        ...
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
       ...
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  

/etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
192.168.56.103 master1
10.0.2.9 master1
```

Comment: Remove the CLOSE_WAIT pid which is shown in netstat command and see if it works. Pod and service definition looks fine to me.

Comment: Try to use curl to access the PodIP:8080 from the vm,  then access  ServiceIP:8080, then localhost:30003, what's the results?

Comment: Are you running kubernetes in minikube? If so, run `minikube service shinyinfo-jenkins-svc --url` inside your vm. This will give you url to access the app. Use that url.

Comment: @KunLi please check my edition two, I provide more information.

Comment: So, you can't accecc service-ip:8080 from vm ? That means something wrong with endpoints. what's your output of `kubectl get svc,ep` ?

Comment: @KunLi my vm has two network interfaces, which have ip 10.0.2.9 (from vm to internet) and 192.168.56.103 (from windows host to vm). Both work which following command cur 192.168.56.103:30003, and 10.0.2.9:30003. Why curl localhost:30003 does not work? Please see edition 3 for detail. Cluster ip is 10.101.23.232, it also works curl 10.101.23.232:30003.

Comment: Localhost should work. Maybe you can use tcpdump to snoop the pod's interface to see what's the difference between accessing localhost:30003 and  10.0.2.9:30003. Also, check the iptable rules of this service may be helpful.

Comment: @KunLi I just noticed that dashboard visiting by 10.0.2.9:32000 and 192.168.56.103:32000 both work. But localhost:32000 does NOT work. Does that give more hints why localhost does not work?

Comment: I think tcpdump output will give you some hints. a NAT issue or something.

Comment: @KunLi What is tcpdump command arguments I shall use if it is NAT issue?

Comment: Since you are using calico,  you can get the calico network interface through your pod's ip, the just run `tcpdump -nn -i calico-inter`, that's done.